# Calculating monthly averages in R with a large dataset spanning several years

Tags: r, date, average

I've looked around but haven't found a solution that quite matches my problem.

I have a dataset (df1) with daily river flow readings, from 1945 to 1981 - so it's a very big dataset.

I want to calculate the average flow for every month, each year. I can do this in Excel using Pivot Tables, but I'm wondering if it would be a lot less laborious in R.

My problem is twofold. Firstly, I'm having trouble conversing the dates to an actual date format (despite trying recommended code), and secondly, once I have the date sorted, I'm not sure how to aggregate monthly averages for every year in the dataset. I'm fairly new to R - I've been looking up tutorials where possible but this particular problem does not seem to have an easily found solution.

So, my data looks like this:

```
         X1    X2
1 01/10/1945 0.835
2 02/10/1945 0.835
3 03/10/1945 0.835
4 04/10/1945 0.835
5 05/10/1945 0.835
6 06/10/1945 0.433
```

The date is initially character format, so I'm using the code

```
df1$X1<-as.Date(df1$X1,"%m/%d/%Y")
```

To try to convert it to date format, but for some reason it keeps mucking up, with several gaps in the dates:

```
8132  1968-05-01  4.163
8133  1968-06-01  4.134
8134  1968-07-01  1.464
8135  1968-08-01  1.682
8136  1968-09-01  1.036
8137  1968-10-01  0.564
8138  1968-11-01  0.575
8139  1968-12-01  0.547
8140        <NA> 10.590
8141        <NA> 16.760
8142        <NA>  3.879
8143        <NA> 11.410
```

The dates display in sets of 12, so I'm assuming the problem is relating to some confusion with "months", but I've tried a few different combinations of d/m/Y and none of them are working.

So to sum up,

- How can I convert data spanning multiple years into a date format without R becoming confused?
- Once the dates are sorted, how can I produce monthly averages when my data spans multiple years?

Many thanks,

I

Comment: Can you show the character strings that are generating the `NA`?

Comment: Note that `as.Date("13/10/1945", "%m/%d/%Y")` would return `NA`. Is it possible that your dates are formatted according to `%d/%m/%Y`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use Lubridate to convert your dates, and dplyr to manipulate your dataframe. Looking at your data, your dates seems to be in the format day / month / year (dmy with Lubridate).

Assuming your dataframe is called df :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- mutate(df, X1 = dmy(X1),Year = year(X1), Month = month(X1))
df <- group_by(df, Month, Year)
df <- summarise(df, result = mean(X2) )
```

You can even chain these commands to make it shorter :

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate( X1 = dmy(X1),Year = year(X1), Month = month(X1)) %>%
  group_by(Month, Year) %>%
  summarise(result = mean(X2) )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just managed to give this a try back at the office. It seems to be working perfectly; putting this code through converts the csv into exactly what I need. Thank you very much - you have spared me several hours of fiddling pivot tables!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using base function, `aggregate()` after date conversion:

```
df$X1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$X1, "%m/%d/%Y"))  # US BASED SHORT DATES
df$X1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$X1, "%d/%m/%Y"))  # NON-US BASED SHORT DATES

df$month <- as.numeric(format(df$X1, '%m'))
df$year <- as.numeric(format(df$X1, '%Y'))

aggdf <- aggregate(X2 ~ month + year, df, FUN=mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm(list = ls())
setwd('path')
df<-read.csv('path/*.csv')
flow<-df[,2]
dt<-ts(flow, frequency=12, start=c(1942,1))
Month <-  factor(cycle(dt), levels = 1:12, labels = month.abb)
tmd<-tapply(dt, list(year = floor(time(dt)), month = Month), c)
write.csv(tmd, 'path/*.csv'
```

Comment: Could you provide some commentary on your answer?